# Route incoming traffic with ingress master/minion

Tags: authentication, nginx, kubernetes, routes

Greetings fellow humans,

i am trying to route all traffic incoming to my cluster with the following annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://my-auth-service/
```

I followed the tutorials and i still have not achieved to route every request to my auth module. I am following a strategy of master-minion. When I check the constructed nginx file the annotation is not found.

I tried as well something like this in one of my minon ingress files

```
auth_request /auth;
auth_request_set $auth_service $upstream_http_auth_service;
proxy_pass    $request_uri
proxy_set_header X-foo-Token $auth_service;
```

I am using the following ingress controller version

```
Image:       nginx/nginx-ingress:1.8.1
Ports:       80/TCP, 443/TCP, 9113/TCP, 8081/TCP
Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
```

Samples:

**Master ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: master-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "master"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: <cluster-ip>
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://my-auth-service/
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.myurl.com
    secretName: secret-tls

  rules:
  - host: app.myurl.com
```

**Minion ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pod-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.org/mergeable-ingress-type: "minion"

    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://my-auth-service/
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
      # auth_request /new-auth-service;
      # auth_request_set $new_auth_service $upstream_http_new_auth_service;
      # proxy_pass    $request_uri
      # proxy_set_header X-foo-Token $new_auth_service;
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName={{ .Values.serviceName }} rewrite=/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.clusterHost }} 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /{{ .Values.serviceName }}/
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ .Values.serviceName }}
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Do you want to use [nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/mergeable-ingress-types) or [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) as Ingress Controller ?
Annotations that start with `nginx.org` are used only by the `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress` Ingress Controller.

Comment: i am using kubernetes/ingress-nginx as Ingress controller, that helps understanding a bit the behavior, however the tags i have for using nginx.org work perfectly, which based on your comment is a bit weird

Comment: So following that logic and the documentation i will give the following annotation a try: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url`

Comment: As far as I know, `Mergeable Types` concept in `nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress` does not work in the same way in `kubernetes/ingress-nginx`.
I found question about `mergeable ingress type` [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3031).
In addition you can find more infrmation how it works in `kubernetes/ingress-nginx` [here](https://diazjf.github.io/2018/05/15/kubernetes-nginx-mergeable-types.html) under "Other".

Comment: thanks for the help, i was able to figure out a solution and make it work :)

Answer (score 1):

so i was able to make it work. First of all, the urls provided by `matt-j` helped be a lot to figure out a solution.

Turns out that i was using `nginx-stable` for my ingress controller, as in the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) suggested, i needed to use the new ingress controller version. i followed the instructions for a full reset, since i am working on my staging env. (for production i might go with a 0 downtime approach). Once installed, I ran into an known issue which is related to the webhooks, similar error can be seen [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5401). Basically one solution for overcoming this error is to delete the `validatingwebhookconfigurations`. Finally I applied the ingress config and made some adjustments to use the proper annotations, which made the magic.

NOTE: I ran into an issue regarding of how forwarding the auth request to my internal cluster service, to fix that i am using the FQDN of kubernetes pod.

NOTE 2: I removed the concept of master minion, since they the merging in kubernetes/ingress-nginx happens automatically more info [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/)

Here are the fixed samples:

MAIN INGRESS

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: master-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: <PUBLIC IP>
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
```

CHILD INGRESS

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.serviceName }}-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://<SERVICE NAME>.<NAMESPACE>.svc.cluster.local # using internal FQDN 
spec:
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.clusterHost }} 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /{{ .Values.serviceName }}(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: {{ .Values.serviceName }}
          servicePort: 80
```